# iOS Animations with swf files for UIButtons

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, flash

I am developping an iOS game, and I work with a drawer for the animations. The problem is, the files he gave to me are in .swf. I see that .swf files are not supported by iOS, and that i can convert them into HTML5, which is supported by iOS for example.

My question is, how can I could associate those animations (that are in .swf and should be converted but what would be the best extension in my case ?) with UIButtons for example ?

Thanks in advance ! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you get the .fla files the .swf files were created from you can convert the animations into animated .gif files or other files that you could use in iOS. Flash Professional has many publishing options. If you do not have Flash Professional I believe there is a fully functional 30 day trial. http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=flash

Or you could ask for another format from the artist.

I know of no way to use a swf which runs in the Flash Player on an iOS device.

Comment: Much depends on your platform and which codexes you have available. In Flash Professional click File > Export > Export Movie and then choose your selected format.